# Find the critical points of $f(x,y) = 9-2x+4y-x^2-4y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

What I did:

Found partial derivatives:

$$f_x=-2x-2$$

$$f_y=-8y+4$$

$$f_x = -2x-2 = 0 \implies x = -1$$

$$f_y = -8y+4 = 0 \implies y = 1/2$$

So is it $(-1, 1/2)$?

Comment: Yeah I was just making sure because my last example included solving them simultaneously whereas in this case it was individually, so just had to make sure it was still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we just get that $$f(x,y)\le 11$$ for $$x=-1,y=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: yes i mean that